# select columns from one table using count function of another table in sql

Tags: mysql

run_software

```
runID   Release
1   X
2   X
3   Y
4   Z
5   Y
6   X
7   Y
8   Z
9   X
10  Z
```

---

```
testcase        

testID  runID   Result
T_1          1  PASS
T_2          1  FAIL
T_3          1  PASS
T_4          2  PASS
T_5          2  FAIL
T_6          3  PASS
T_7          4  FAIL
T_8          3  PASS
T_9          3  FAIL
T_10         5  PASS
T_11         5  FAIL
T_12         3  PASS
```

---

1) From run_software table we can understand X software run on runID's `1, 2,6,9`

2) Take runID - 1 and come to testcase table.
Here we have 7 testID's with runID 1. 
From these 7 testID's we need to measure the TC count and percentage of PASS/FAIL using group by Result and runID.

AIM: Ultimate aim is to find the latest 3 Release's and its runID's with PASS percentage by considering max testcase count.

Eg. if 'X' release executed on runID's 1, 2, 3, 4 with each 10, 12, 9, 21 testcases respectively, we should consider runID 4 for release 'X' to measure the 'PASS %'

Desired OutPut:

```
considering PASS% is > 60
Release runID   Result  PASS %
X   1   PASS    66.66
Y   3   PASS    75
Z   4   FAIL    0
```

---

To be understanding

```
Release 'X' has runID's - 1, 2 , 6, 9 with 3, 2, 0 , 0 TestID's respecively
    Hence, X finalized runID '1' with 66.66 as PASS% (2 PASS & 1 FAIL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear actually, but it should be something like that I guess:

```
SELECT r.Release, r.runID, (CASE WHEN subq.PassPerc >= 60 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END) AS Result, subq.PASSPerc 
    FROM run_software AS r 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT p.runID, (100 * p.passed / t.total) AS PASSPerc 
            FROM (SELECT runID, COUNT(*) AS passed FROM testcase WHERE Result = 'PASS' GROUP BY runID) AS p
            INNER JOIN (SELECT runID, COUNT(*) AS total FROM testcase GROUP BY runID) AS t ON t.runID = p.runID 
            GROUP BY p.runID, p.passed, t.total) AS subq
        ON subq.runID = r.runID 
    GROUP BY r.Release, r.runID, subq.PASSPerc
```